# Material Design Date Picker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, material-design, angular-material

I am developing an application using angular 1.X and angular material.  My application requires a date picker that can accept custom predefined dates that can be selected or deselected.  Angular's built in date picker does not have this functionality so I was wondering if anyone knows of a date picker that can do this that also fits into the material design look and feel.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This one is a nice datetime picker, I am using it in one of my applications. Its easy to implement and well documented.

[Material DateTimePicker](https://github.com/logbon72/angular-material-datetimepicker)

[Live Demo](https://logbon72.github.io/angular-material-datetimepicker/)

```
<md-input-container flex-gt-md="30">
    <label>Timepicker Only</label>
    <input mdc-datetime-picker date="false" time="true" type="text" id="time" short-time="true"
           show-todays-date
           placeholder="Time"
           min-date="minDate"
           format="hh:mm a"
           ng-change="vm.saveChange()"
           ng-model="time">
</md-input-container>
```